# Python Regex Behaviour

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to parse a text document with data in the following format: `24036 -977`. I need to separate the numbers into separate values, and the way I've done that is with the following steps.

```
values = re.search("(.*?)\s(.*)")
x = values.group(1)
y = values.gropu(2)
```

This does the job, however I was curious about why using (.*?) in the second group causes the regex to fail? I tested it in the online regex tester(https://regex101.com/r/bM2nK1/1), and adding the ? in causes the second group to return nothing. Now as far as I know `.*?` means to take any value unlimited times, as few times as possible, and the `.*` is just the greedy version of that. What I'm confused about is why the non greedy version`.*?` takes that definition to mean capturing nothing?

Comment: A [must-read](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#lazy_solution).

Comment: @stribizhev also http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/113237/when-you-should-not-use-regular-expressions

Comment: @JustinWang don't forget to mark the answer most suited to your problem as correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because it means to match the previous token, the `*`, as few times as possible, which is 0 times. If you would it to extend to the end of the string, add a `$`, which matches the end of string. If you would like it to match at least one, use `+` instead of `*`.

The reason the first group `.*?` matches `24036` is because you have the `\s` token after it, so the fewest amount of characters the `.*?` could match and be followed by a `\s` is `24036`.

Answer (score 1):

@iobender has pointed out the answer to your question.

But I think it's worth mentioning that if the numbers are separated by space, you can just use `split`:

```
>>> '24036 -977'.split()
['24036', '-977']
```

This is simpler, easier to understand and often faster than `regex`.

Comment: Yep, this is actually a better implementation. I've just mostly been doing text parsing in python, so I defaulted to regex, so it didn't occur to me to look for other things. Thanks

Comment: @JustinWang, no problem - I know many people who default to `regex` for the simplest things, always worth trying another route first.